# How to split a stream in gulp

Tags: gulp

Basically I have a set of files that I process using markdown and what not. After doing this initial processing, I'd like to split the stream into two:

1. First, 1..1 mapping with additional processing like layout
2. Secondly, mapping all the files into one, like index, without the layouts applied above

Is it ok to save the stream into a variable and just keep piping? Here's my current task:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    var entries = gulp.src('./log/*.md')
        .pipe(frontMatter())
        .pipe(markdown());

    var templated = entries
        .pipe(applyTemplate())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/log'));

    var index = entries
        .pipe(index())
        .pipe(applyIndexTemplate())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

    return merge(templated, index);
}
```

I could use [lazypipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) and/or just construct the pipe multiple times, but is there another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options), "multiple destinations can be piped to safely" and the original example is correct:

```
var entries = gulp.src('./log/*.md')
    .pipe(frontMatter())
    .pipe(markdown());

var templated = entries
    .pipe(applyTemplate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/log'));

var index = entries
    .pipe(index())
    .pipe(applyIndexTemplate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

return merge(templated, index);
```

Comment: I tried this but was getting strange behaviour, could have been the gulp actions I was doing but if I saved the stream at a point (your `entities` var) then used it like you do to do 2 differing things on the stream it seemed to apply both changes to both outputs, however if I were to just put it in one long stream without saving it (i.e remove all variables and just have it one huge daisy chain of pipes on a single stream) it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same issue as @Grofit... I ended up just doing `gulp.src('dist/**').pipe(...)` twice instead of saving as `distFiles` then calling pipe on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
var gulpClone = require("gulp-clone");
var eventStream = require('event-stream');

var entries = gulp.src('./log/*.md')
    .pipe(frontMatter())
    .pipe(markdown());

var templated = entries
    .pipe(gulpClone())
    .pipe(applyTemplate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/log'));

var index = entries
    .pipe(gulpClone())
    .pipe(index())
    .pipe(applyIndexTemplate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

return eventStream.merge(templated, index);
```